# How to use versioning when i use different projects for frontend and backend

Tags: git

I have a project that uses Angular frontend and Spring-Boot backend. How should I set up my repositories? Is it common to use submodules or different repositories for frontend and backend or would I still just use one big repository? I cannot really make out pro's and con's for either way.

Comment: We use separate repos for frontend and backend and then a third for managing deployments of the two.

Comment: @jmoney And then you included 1 and 2 to the third one as submodules?

Comment: Yep that's how we do it.